# Need to move list item to another list when the due date us past without code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have a scenario where I have to move list items to another list when the due dates are passed(without code).

There are more than 10000 items on the list and to create a workflow to solve this will not be a good solution. Since there will be many number of workflow instances which will be running for an unknown period of time.

I have an option of creating a retention policy to start a workflow when the item is past the due date(this is an option) which will move the item to the other list and the workflow will too end there.

I wanted to check if there are any other better options which will solve the problem.

Could you please let me know if there is any better option to handle this scenario?

Comment: Go ahead with your solution, In my opinion, it's the better one without code!

Answer (score 2):

Setting up retention policy is the best no-code solution.